# How do I disable drag-and-drop text editing in Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide

How do I disable drag-and-drop text editing in Arduino IDE?  This is very annoying.  If not careful, this causes code to move around when trying to copy and paste...

Comment: I cannot find any settings in 'Preferences' that control drag-and-drop functionality.

Comment: If you cannot a corresponding setting in the preferences file, the IDE doesn't have this feature. The Arduino IDE is really not a good IDE, so you might want to move to a more professional IDE

Comment: ctrl-z is your friend

Comment: When I did a bigger (proof of concept) project, I use Visual Studio, Eclipse (or any decent IDE), and you still can use the Arduino IDE to compile.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers - what do you mean "still can use the Arduino IDE to compile"? do you mean - copy from the other IDE back into Arduino IDE for the compile and load?  Or do you mean, you can use the other IDE and somehow get the Arduino IDE to recognize changes in an external IDE to compile against?

Comment: I mean the last ... edit in the external IDE, and press the compile button (or shortcut) of the Arduino IDE. I remember there was an issue one way around (I think the Arduino does not recognize automatically changes), so you have to make the .ino file stable (just let it load a C++ (startup) class that executes everything.

Comment: Thanks @MichelKeijzers - I will give it a try!

Comment: In the preferences dialog, there is a checkbox labeled “Use external editor”.